# Tutorial XML Parser Groovy Namespace Handling

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy, namespaces

i found this supergroovy function of XmlParser().parseText(...).

It works fine for me without namespaces... now i have the following XML (SoapRequest):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://xxx" xmlns:xsd="http://xxy" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://xxz">
       <soap:Body>
         <MG_Input xmlns="http://yxx">
            <Accnr>001</Accnr> 
            [...]
```

My target is to acquire the Accnr over the XmlParser.
I assumed that it could work this way:

```
input = new File('c:/temp/03102890.xml-out')

def soapns = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://xxx",'soap')
def xsdns = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://xxy")
def xsins = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://xxz")
def ordns = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://yxx")



xml = new XmlParser().parseText(input.getText())
println xml[soapns.Envelope][soapns.Body][ordns.MG_Input][Accnr][0].text()
```

But this doesnt really work...

Has anybody an idea of how to handle this 'easy'? I just cant get it to work with examples from google...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your expression was incorrect - the `xml` var is already the root element of the xml document (in this case `soap:Envelope`) - so you just need to traverse from there. So, the expression you're looking for is:

```
println xml[soapns.Body][ordns.MG_Input].Accnr[0].text()
```

Comment: Hmm i dont know why, but it works now with 

`println xml[soapns.Body].MG_Input.Accnr[0].text()`

I think there is another good way to solve it with GPath. But this is also a further task to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Tip for others:

you can just print the String that you parsed. for example, above print xml after this line  `xml = new XmlParser().parseText(input.getText())` , then you will get the top element, it will look similar to a JSON array, then you can easily traverse on that. Don't include the topmost element you see.